# Finding the diameter of a n-cube

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is there a general method that can be used find the diameter of a n-cube? In particular what if I want to find the diameter of a 4-cube can someone suggest me a method or hint. I would much appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diameter of an [$n$-cube graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_graph) is $n$.  For let $v$ be a vertex of $Q_n$.  Since $Q_n$ is vertex-transitive, it doesn't matter which $v$ we choose, so say it is the one whose $n$ coordinates are all zeroes.  Then $v'$, the farthest vertex from $v$, is clearly the one whose $n$ coordinates are all ones, at a distance of $n$.

Comment: The distance is $\sqrt{n}$ as in the answer below...

Comment: That's the diameter in a different metric (sum of absolute values of coordinate differences), but I'm guessing the OP wanted the Euclidean diameter. In particular, for $n = 2$, the diameter is $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @peder The question was tagged [tag:graph-theory], not [tag:geometry], so I gave the graph-theoretic answer, not the geometric one.

Comment: @MJD Thanks. Yes I wanted the graph theory definition/answer. But I find John's answer useful too although it's not exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @Peder: Apologies for misreading the OP's intentions; didn't mean to impugn you. I should have read more carefully (and perhaps the OP could have disambiguated "diameter" for us with something more than the tags).

Answer (score 11):

The diameter of a set is the distance between the two points that are farthest apart (more or less, with some "supremum" stuff for more complicated objects). For a standard unit cube in $n$-dimensions, the vertices are points $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, where each $x_i$ is either $0$ or $1$, and two points at the opposite ends of a diagonal in this situation are $(0, 0, \ldots, 0)$ and $(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$. The distance between these is $$\sqrt{ (1-0)^2 + \ldots (1-0)^2} = \sqrt{n}.$$

So the diameter of an $n$-cube whose side has length $1$  is $\sqrt{n}$.